# Problem running scripts against SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, unit-testing

We have some scripts that we run as part of our unit tests.

This worked fine until today.

- We have tried running scripts with both windows and sql authentication.
- We have no problems logging in using sql manager

Anybody have any ideas why we get the following error:

```
Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe.

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Communication link failure.
```

Thanks

Shiraz

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replys. The actual appears to be a password problem, which used up all the connections. The process was not listening because there were no available connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure the protocols you are using to connect to it are setup correctly. I suggest you enable "Shared Memory" and "TCP/IP".

Answer (score 1):

Ask around, try and determine what was changed on your environment--by who, and how--that caused a working process to stop working. If succesful, you will (a) have a strong lead on discovering the details of what's going wrong, and (b) be in a position to ensure it doesn't recur. (Just solving the tech side might not prevent it from happening again...)